# Sugar CRM - Not able to create new fields on Module builder

Tags: php, debian, sugarcrm

I'm having a hard time figuring out why I wasn't able to create a new field on the module builder of Sugar CRM CE.

I thought it could be a file permissions issue, but after many forum posts and user guides from the SugarCRM community, I have not yet resolve my issue.

To give a background on the issue, here are steps I've taken:

1. I installed a Debian image on a VM
2. Updated the packages and installed a LAMP server (with PHP 5.6)
3. Downloaded the required prerequisite modules
4. Configured the php.ini as per the installation guide
5. Ran 'chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sugarcrm'
6. Ran 'chmod 775 -R /var/www/html/sugarcrm'
7. Ran the installation page of Sugar (Setup went well until the Registration page where it just outputs 'Permission Denied')
8. Create a new package on Modules Builder.
9. Create a new module
10. Create a new field (Failed. only created the label)

Hope you guys can help me with this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you have a look in custom/ModuleBuilder, find your module, and see if the field is being written to the vardefs.php file of the module in question? I've had a similar issue, but it was on the more recent 7.x versions.

Comment: Hi @Reisclef, nothing was written on the vardefs of the module. The fields array did not append anything. It does not even work when I tried to change the permissions of it as well.

Comment: Sounds similar to what I had. If this works, I'll post it as an answer, but I'll comment for now. Can you try adding the following into your php.ini and restarting Apache?    `opcache.revalidate_freq = 0`

Comment: That did it! You saved me a lot of time. Thanks @Reisclef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I previously encountered this, I worked with Sugar support to establish the cause of the problem.

We were able to narrow it down to opcache by disabling opcache, which worked. However, after some investigation, we came to the conclusion that it was the particular setting [opcache.revalidate_freq](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq).

By setting this to 0 (to check for changes on every request), we were able to work with opcache. While this wasn't ideal, this was the Sugar recommended solution to the problem. Also, it allowed us to continue using most of the benefits of opcache.

So you can resolve this by adding the following line to php.ini and restart apache:

```
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For those having the same issue with version 9.0 and PHP version 7.1, the above solution works.